# Game center, how to handle invites

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, game-center, gkmatchmaker

I am working on a multiplayer game. For listing, ending and creating matches I do NOT use `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`. So I have custom view controller to show all the matches.

My problem is, I can not handle match invites. I need it for updating my view.

Scenerio :

- Alice launches game and looking on invites list and thinking about accepting or declining the matches.
- Bob sends an invite for a new match.
- Alice gets invite notification from notification center, but does not tap on it and it disappears.(If she taps on it, I can handle)

Now I need to add the Bobs invite to the list(and update UI). But I do not any handler get called about invite.

I have already tried registering handler after the player has authenticated like `[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] setInviteHandler:]`
It never called, I do not know what for is it.